# calcul time between 2 hours in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I try to calculate the time elapsed between 2 hours but also to make a sum for the day and the week.

I tried several methods but none was congruent and I dry completely, no more ideas.

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length = 64, verbose_name = _("Title"))
start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = _("Start time"))
end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = _("End time"))
allDay = models.BooleanField(blank = True, default = False, verbose_name = _("All day"), help_text = _("If it's a full day work, just click 'Now' for start/end"))
week = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "working week")

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.title)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.week = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]
    if self.allDay:
        self.start = datetime.datetime(year = datetime.datetime.today().year, month = datetime.datetime.today().month, day = datetime.datetime.today().day, hour=8, minute=00)
        self.end = datetime.datetime(year = datetime.datetime.today().year, month = datetime.datetime.today().month, day = datetime.datetime.today().day, hour=17, minute=30)
    super(Timesheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the hope that you can help me.

Regards,

Comment: The time between 2 hours is 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant difference between two variables having only time part you can use datetime to achieve this.

```
from datetime import datetime
time1 = '09:00'
time2 = '13:15' 
fmt = '%H:%M'
difference1 = datetime.strptime(time2, fmt) - datetime.strptime(time1, fmt)
difference2 = datetime.strptime(time1, fmt) - datetime.strptime(time2, fmt)

print("difference 1 = {} \ndifference2 = {}".format(difference1, difference2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I extract only time from my DateTimeField ?